# JS then() not waiting for func result

Tags: javascript, async-await

```
export const getLocalStorageItem = (key, defaultValue = null) => {
        const user = loadedStore.getState().session.user;
        makeRequest(`/account/${user.id}/localstorage`, 'get').then((response) => {
                    try {
                        if (_.isNull(response.json.localstorage)) {
                            return defaultValue;
                        }
                        const formattedKey = `${key}_${user.id}`;
                        debugger
                        return response.json.localstorage[formattedKey] ? JSON.parse(response.json.localstorage[formattedKey].replaceAll("'", '"')) : defaultValue;
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err); //eslint-disable-line-no-console } }); }
```

```
getColumns() {
        const {
            permissions
        } = this.props;
        let columns = [];
        columns = getPartnerColumns(permissions);
        const columnOptions = getPartnerColumns(permissions);
        const tableViewOptions = [];
        if (permissions === 'admin') {
            const localStorageColumns = getLocalStorageItem(this.localStorageColumnConfigurationKey);
            debugger // If the user has a saved column list, use it. if (localStorageColumns) { columns = [ ...localStorageColumns.map((c) => { const options = columnOptions.find((opt) => opt.id === c); return options; }) ]; } }
```

Why isn't the return value from the function seen in the first code presented being saved in the variable const localStorageColumns?

How can I wait for the fund's result?

I think that the request isn't fullfiled by the time the function returns, specially because the 1st debugger point is the one after the function and only then the one inside the function.

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable (e.g. not on two very very long lines). https://beautifier.io/ may be helpful.

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:async-await] but aren't using those keywords (perhaps you should, they generally make promise based code more readable).

Answer (score 0):

Promises are asynchronous in javaScript, which means that the result of a promise is available "later" or more exactly as soon as the asynchronous instructions finish, and javascript continues to execute the rest of the instructions while the async stuffs are being executed in the background.
If you want javascript to wait for a promise to either resolve and reject, you should use async/await as show in the snippet bellow.

Please find more on promise here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises

```
export const getLocalStorageItem = async (key, defaultValue = null) => {
  const user = loadedStore.getState().session.user;

  const item = await makeRequest(`/account/${user.id}/localstorage`, 'get').then(
    (response) => {
      try {
        if (_.isNull(response.json.localstorage)) { return defaultValue; }
        const formattedKey = `${key}_${user.id}`;
        return response.json.localstorage[formattedKey] ?
          JSON.parse(response.json.localstorage[formattedKey].replaceAll("'", '"')) :
          defaultValue;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  
    return item ?? defaultValue;
}
```